# Universal Approximation Capabilities of Mixture of Weibulls

Tags: approximation, weibull-distribution, density-estimation, finite-mixture-model, growth-mixture-model

Can a mixture of $N$ Weibull distributions approximate any continuous density with non-negative support, if $N$ is sufficiently large? (If so, a reference to the proof would be greatly appreciated).

(Edit: this is not a homework problem, so you are free to provide the answer directly).

(Edit 2: question edited to address lack of clarity, as pointed out by whuber - thanks for requesting additional clarity on the question!)

Comment: Ultimately this sounds tautological: just define "well-behaved" as any density that can be approximated, according to some specific metric, arbitrarily closely by mixtures of Weibulls!  If you adopt a [standard definition of Weibull distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), though, you will be unable to represent any distribution without non-negative support.  Perhaps you intend to include location-shifted Weibulls?

Comment: Agree with @whuber , though the question mentions *"approximate any continuous density with non-negative support"*

Comment: A rigorous, detailed answer would depend on the sense in which you mean "approximate;" but intuitively, since any Dirac delta measure supported on a positive number $a$ is the weak limit of Weibull$(k, a/\Gamma(1+1/k))$ densities as $k\to\infty,$ basically all distributions (continuous or not) can be approximated by mixtures of Weibulls.

Comment: Ah thank you so much!! This is the type of result I’m looking for. Any chance you could point me in the direction of some further resources/reading on this, as I’m not familiar with the theorem you discussed?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity.